# Why is from_line and to from csv-parse on my CSV file not reading the expected amount of rows?

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv, parsing

I am trying to read a .csv file so large that holding it all in a variable will exceed memory. So I would like to process only part of the .csv file at a time. I was reading through the CSV Parse options and found `from_line` that starts from a requested line number and `to` which will handle a requested number of records. I figured if I set how many records I want to process at a time, I could start with the first record and add the number processed rows so the beginning of the next loop will start with the first unprocessed row and so on.

However when I run the code, the actual number of rows read is not what I set `to` to and they number of rows processed on each loop is varied. Sometimes its only 3 rows. Sometimes only 63 rows are processed. Both are less than the number of rows I set `to` to. Additionally, the sum of all the rows does not match what is in the .CSV file. Sometimes its more ( twice as any records), sometimes its less (half as many records) depending on what I set `to` to. Can someone see why I'm not getting the correct number of rows?

```
   import { parse } from 'csv-parse';

   function main(){
       let dataList = [{}];
       let startLine = 2
       const numRows = 500;

       while( dataList.length != 0){
            const data = await this.getCSVData(startLine, numRows);
           //function to process the rows
            
            dataList = data;
            startLine += numRows;
        }
    }

     async function readCSVFile(filePath: string, fromLine, toLine): Promise<object[]> {
        const results: object[] = [];       
        const parseOptions = {from_line: fromLine, to: toLine}
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            .pipe(parse(parseOptions))
            .on('data', (data) => {
                results.push(data)
            })
            .on('end', () => resolve(results))
            .on('error', (error) => reject(error));
        });
    }
    
    async function getCSVData(startLine, numRows){
            try{
                return await this.readCSVFile("fileName.csv", startLine, numRows);
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
            };
    }
```